# Best to let general react component subscribe from store or manually pass it data?

Tags: react-redux

I am just starting out with React and Redux and I stumbled upon a tricky problem.

Say I have a general React component(let's call it **FriendSelector**) that can be used in many places on the site. **FriendSelector** needs to have an array of friend objects to function.

Do I make **FriendSelector** a container component using connect() from the ReactRedux library and use mapStateToProps to fetch whatever it want from the store

*or*

do I manually send a list of data from whatever component that uses **FriendSelector** as props, like this:

```
let friends = this.context.store.getState().friends

<MyComponent>
    <FriendSelector friends={friends} />
</MyComponent>
```

or is this bad practice?

---

Personally I think the option #1 is not so good because then I have to make sure my store has a friends property containing an array else the  component won't work.

But when I think about option #2 it looks like it don't follow the uni-directional data flow because a component should only be allowed to get its prop from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Whether connecting your component to the store or getting the required properties from parent components is completely up to you. It depends on your app architecture.

Read [this popular post](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) about presentational vs. container components.

Consider that feeding component by directly querying the state with `getState()` is generally considered bad practice. That's the reason why redux exposes `connect` method.

Comment: I would like to use the first alternative, with connect like you said. But I am not sure if it's good to let the Container select what data it needs from the store by using mapStateToProps because the store might not have that data at that time.

Comment: @Doodlemeat Your application renders always as a function of your state. Therefore not having a piece of data available, should be a scenario your components should take into account.